# Inspecting / modifying Emacs hooks for minor modes

Tags: emacs

I use the following to enable `linum-mode` for Python buffers:

```
(defun my-python-mode-hook () 
  (linum-mode 1)) 
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)
```

However, my understanding of hooks is still quite limited. As far as I understand, the code above **adds** a function to `python-mode-hook` so I assume this hook has **already** been defined, and may even have some code in it already. With this:

1. Does Emacs define a hook of the form `<minor_mode_name>-hook` for all minor modes? Or do the modes themshelves define them?
2. How can I look up the code added to a hook already?
3. How can I change elements of that hook?

---

This question is partly motivated by this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/274) for [elpy](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy) where `elpy-mode` seems to have left a hook for `python-mode` that doesn't go away after uninstalling elpy.

Comment: Minor nit: `python-mode` is actually a major mode.  Major modes are exclusive (i.e. only one active at a time in a given buffer), while any number of minor modes (e.g. `linum-mode`) can be active.  Hooks work the same for major and minor modes, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Emacs does not define a minor mode hook automatically, but you can define one with the `:after-hook` keyword (as per manual page for [defining minor mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html)).  (*UPDATE*: as per Legoscia's last comment, the minor-mode hook gets defined automatically as of emacs version 24.3.90.  Thanks, Legoscia!)

(2) hooks are just variables, so you can inspect them as you would any other variable (e.g., `C-h v` or `M-x describe-variable RET some-hook`).

(3) you can use `add-hook` and `remove-hook` to change elements of the hook (see the manual on [setting hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Setting-Hooks.html)), eg:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)

(remove-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my-python-mode-hook)
```

(Note, by the way, that it's preferable to use named functions in your hooks rather than anonymous `lambda`s because you can use `remove-hook` on your named functions.)

Comment: A minor mode defined with `define-minor-mode` will automatically get a hook variable.  `:after-hook` is for running code after the hook has run.

Comment: Are you sure?  The minimal example of `(define-minor-mode hungry-mode ...)` on the [defining minor modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html) manual page does not generate a hook variable (meaning `hungry-mode-hook` or somesuch; it does, of course, define `hungry-mode`).  Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, the documentation could be more complete, but the definition of the hook variable inside the definition of `define-minor-mode` is not conditional; it's always present.

Comment: Huh.  Thing is: when evaluating that `hungry-mode` minor mode definition, the only two variables defined are `hungry-mode` and `hungry-mode-map`.  Where is the hook variable?

Comment: Ah, you're right: `hungry-mode-hook` is only defined as of Emacs 24.3.90.

Comment: Edited the answer to incorporate that information.  Nice catch!

Comment: The hook variable *declaration* is sort of optional. If that's recently been added in explicitly, it's possibly for lexical-vs-dynamic binding reasons. In any case, all mode functions defined via the `define-*-mode` macros will run a `MODENAME-hook`; that's been the case for a long time. The `add-hook` function doesn't mind if the specified hook variable isn't bound, so you can go ahead and use `(add-hook 'some-example-mode-hook 'myfunc)` for any `some-example-mode`, regardless of whether that mode has been loaded, and regardless of whether the hook variable is currently defined.